# Pedestrian Detection with unique identifier

Tags: opencv, detection, video-tracking

Hi I am currently using OpenCV implementation of HOG and Haar Cascade to perform pedestrian detection and bounding them on a video feed.

However, I want to assign an unique id (number) for every pedestrian entering the video feed with the id remains the same until the pedestrian leaves the video feed. Since frames are processed one after another without regard of previous frame I wasn't sure how to implement this in the simplest but effective way possible.

Do I really need to use tracking algorithm like camshift or Kalman in which I have no knowledge about and could really use some help. Or is there any simpler way to achieve what I want?

P/S: This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uCbEvXL94Q) is what I wanted to achieve. In fact I posted a similar question here before but that was more towards the detection techniques and this is towards the next step of assigning the unique identifier.

Comment: yes, that's called tracking.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

Keep Track of your Objects in a Vector.
If you compute a new frame, for every Object: search for the nearest Object stored in your Vector. If the distance between the stored object and your current Object is below a certain threshold it is the same Object.

If no Match is found the Object is new. At the end delete all Objects in your Vector that are not associated with an Object of the current frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have thought of this before but what I am afraid of is this: What if the detector "misses" the person during a certain frame, the "nearest Object" approach would've thought the person has left the video feed.

Comment: You could create a counter for each Object. If the counter reaches a certain Value -> discard the Object. So you watch in a certain number of frames and only if the object is missing too long you discard it. This is by far not a very robust way of doing things, that is why i wrote "simple solution" ;-)

Comment: Yeah that is indeed a nice and simple solution :). If you don't mind me asking, do you know any other more reliable way of doing what I want?

Comment: A more elaborate way would be to use Kalman Filter as you already mentioned in your question. You can have a look at this Matlab implementation to see how it works: http://blog.cordiner.net/2011/05/03/object-tracking-using-a-kalman-filter-matlab/

Comment: Oh I did stumble upon Kalman a while back but I have totally no idea how to use it along with my HOG or Haar approach of pedestrian detection. Any good code tutorials suitable for my case? I am using C++ OpenCV btw.

Comment: This is a generall Example about Kalman from OpenCv. Just adapt it to trac your Coordinates and you are done. http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/06/17/simple-kalman-filter-for-tracking-using-opencv-2-2-w-code/

Answer (score 1):

When you will use `detectMultiScale` to get the matches, you will have a `std:Vector<cv:Rect>` structure which will have all the detected pedestrians. While iterating through them for drawing, you can assign a number to each unique `cv::Rect` being detected (you may need to write a slightly deeper test for this, to check for overlapping rectangles) which you can then draw (let's say on the top) of the corresponding rectangle.

HTH

Comment: No offense but you kinda misunderstood my question. I can assign each Rect returned by detectMultiScale an unique identifier. The question arises during the next frame where the person detected on the previous frame may have moved, so how do I ensure that same person still have the same unique id I assigned to him on the previous frame (instead of reassigning him a new unique id).

Comment: Oh I think I didn't make myself clear. You will need to keep the Rect as a global variable (the way @Mailerdaimon suggested).

Comment: I didn´t get that at the first read as well. Maybe you can rephrase your Answer to be more clear. +1 for the good approach ;)

Comment: No worries, you wrote exactly what I meant in any case. :)